# I don't understand the reason this code is not infinity recursive

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm new at Retrofit2. I have a question when reading [this site](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit).
Why [the createService method](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit) in ServiceGenerator is not infinity recursive?

```
public static <S> S createService(
        Class<S> serviceClass, String username, String password) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(username)
            && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        String authToken = Credentials.basic(username, password);
        return createService(serviceClass, authToken);
    }

    return createService(serviceClass, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Maybe can you not do `//omitted` but instead just show us the actual code?

Comment: Probably because TextUtils.isEmpty(null) evaluates as false, and that in the "second" pass first return statement is called...

Comment: @Gotiasits No. TextUtils.isEmpty(null) returns true.

Comment: That actually look like an error in their code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not infinitely recursive because of polymorphism. There are three different createService methods each with different signatures. So if the password and user are both not empty they go to a different createService with the signature (serviceClass, authToken).